# Ruby & MySQL: How to handle missing elements while parsing XML file

Tags: mysql, ruby, xml

Currently I am trying to parse large xml file, Here is the how my xml file looks like:

```
<post>
  <row Id="22" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="9" CreationDate="2008-08-01T12:07:19.500" Score="7" Body="&lt;p&gt;The best way that I know of because of leap years and everything is:&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(2000,3,1);&lt;br&gt;int age = (int)Math.Floor((DateTime.Now - birthDate).TotalDays / 365.25D);&lt;br&gt;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Hope this helps.&lt;/p&gt;" OwnerUserId="17" LastEditorUserId="17" LastEditorDisplayName="Nick" LastEditDate="2008-08-01T15:26:37.087" LastActivityDate="2008-08-01T15:26:37.087" CommentCount="1" CommunityOwnedDate="2011-08-16T19:40:43.080" />

  <row Id="29" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="13" CreationDate="2008-08-01T12:19:17.417" Score="18" Body="&lt;p&gt;There are no HTTP headers that will report the clients timezone so far although it has been suggested to include it in the HTTP specification.&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;If it was me, I would probably try to fetch the timezone using clientside JavaScript and then submit it to the server using Ajax or something.&lt;/p&gt;" OwnerUserId="19" LastActivityDate="2008-08-01T12:19:17.417" CommentCount="0" />

</post>
```

Different between these two records in this XML file is that  doesn't have LastEditDate element. I believe as a result of that I get the following error:

```
/ruby/1.9.2/ubuntuamd1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb:1031:in `dup': can't dup NilClass (TypeError)
    from /soft/ruby/1.9.2/ubuntuamd1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb:1031:in `_parse'
    from /soft/ruby/1.9.2/ubuntuamd1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:1732:in `parse'
    from load.rb:105:in `on_start_element'
    from load.rb:165:in `parse'
```

Here is the code segment that its getting referred:

```
if element == 'row'
  @post_st.execute(attributes['Id'], attributes['PostTypeId'], attributes['AcceptedAnswerId'], attributes['ParentId'], attributes['Score'], attributes['ViewCount'], 
    attributes['Body'], attributes['OwnerUserId'] == nil ? -1 : attributes['OwnerUserId'], attributes['LastEditorUserId'], attributes['LastEditorDisplayName'], 
    DateTime.parse(attributes['LastEditDate']).to_time.strftime("%F %T"), DateTime.parse(attributes['LastActivityDate']).to_time.strftime("%F %T"), attributes['Title'] == nil ? '' : attributes['Title'], 
    attributes['AnswerCount'] == nil ? 0 : attributes['AnswerCount'], attributes['CommentCount'] == nil ? 0 : attributes['CommentCount'], 
    attributes['FavoriteCount'] == nil ? 0 : attributes['FavoriteCount'], DateTime.parse(attributes['CreationDate']).to_time.strftime("%F %T"))
  post_id = attributes['Id']
```

furthermore I think this is the line where I look for `LastEditDate`

```
 DateTime.parse(attributes['LastEditDate']).to_time.strftime("%F %T"), DateTime.parse(attributes['LastActivityDate']).to_time.strftime("%F %T"), attributes['Title'] == nil ? '' : attributes['Title']
```

I guess since the element doesn't exist I get the above mentioned error. I was wondering how do I handle this scenario where if an element doesn't exist set it to a default value. Because while I am parsing these record I insert them into MySQL database. Which has following table structure:

```
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                             |
| post_type_id             | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| accepted_answer_id       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| parent_id                | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| score                    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| view_count               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| body_text                | text         | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| owner_id                 | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| last_editor_user_id      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| last_editor_display_name | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| last_edit_date           | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| last_activity_date       | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| title                    | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| answer_count             | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| comment_count            | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| favorite_count           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| created                  | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I have setup last_edit_date as not null column.

Based on the answer provided I made the change but error still remains the same:

```
  def convert_to_mysql_time(date='1973-01-01T01:01:01.000')
    DateTime.parse(date).to_time.strftime("%F %T")
  end

  def on_start_element(element, attributes)
    if element == 'row'
      @post_st.execute(attributes['Id'], attributes['PostTypeId'], attributes['AcceptedAnswerId'], attributes['ParentId'], attributes['Score'], attributes['ViewCount'],
        attributes['Body'], attributes['OwnerUserId'] == nil ? -1 : attributes['OwnerUserId'], attributes['LastEditorUserId'], attributes['LastEditorDisplayName'],
        convert_to_mysql_time(attributes['LastEditDate']), DateTime.parse(attributes['LastActivityDate']).to_time.strftime("%F %T"), attributes['Title'] == nil ? '' : attributes['Title'],
        attributes['AnswerCount'] == nil ? 0 : attributes['AnswerCount'], attributes['CommentCount'] == nil ? 0 : attributes['CommentCount'],
        attributes['FavoriteCount'] == nil ? 0 : attributes['FavoriteCount'], DateTime.parse(attributes['CreationDate']).to_time.strftime("%F %T"))
      post_id = attributes['Id']
```

Here is the error:

```
/ruby/1.9.2/ubuntuamd1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb:1031:in `dup': can't dup NilClass (TypeError)
    from /soft/ruby/1.9.2/ubuntuamd1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb:1031:in `_parse'
    from /soft/ruby/1.9.2/ubuntuamd1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:1732:in `parse'
    from load.rb:102:in `convert_to_mysql_time'
    from load.rb:109:in `on_start_element'
    from load.rb:169:in `parse'
    from load.rb:169:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would, write a method that converts String dates to `MySQL` dates, and supply it a default value if the nil is supplied to the method, e.g:

```
def convert_to_my_sql_date(date)
    date = '1973-01-01T01:01:01.000' if (date.empty? rescue true) #was added since empty string gets supplied as an argument, and the rescue to make arguments that do not respond to empty? take a default date
    DateTime.parse(date).to_time.strftime("%F %T")
end
```

So when the date is nil it uses the default, then you can now use as below in your method:

```
convert_to_my_sql_date(attributes['LastEditDate'])
```

Comment: How can I check for the nil? can I do the sameway I am doing for other?

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon why do you need to check for nil, you just supply a default value for nil, and any record in your DB with the default value is the one that had the nil

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon what error are you getting, did you use the updated answer, I changed the parameter passed to `DateTime.parse` in method above, and I suppose this should work without issues,except of course your error is not `DateTime` parsing related

Comment: I updated the question. Basically its the same error.

Comment: replace everywhere you are using the `DateTime.parse(...).to_time.strftime("%F %T")` with the method I provided

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48531/discussion-between-find-missing-semicolon-and-bjhaid)

Comment: error is actually now from the the method that you suggested while try its happening when its trying to parse the via the method.